# Continuous Integration

Tags: github, markdown, badge

My badges aren't showing on github README.md file but they show here on stackoverflow. Here are the markdowns:

[image: Build Status]
[image: Coverage Status]

I also noticed that html tags (that used to work in README.md files) now show as plain text. What am I missing?

Comment: Well you should just try as you just did in this question, using `markdown` ;p

Comment: Honestly, I have tried everything I can. I tried using different options provided by Travis and Coveralls: html, image url, markdown, RST etc. Rather than render them just as stackoverflow has done, I just see everything in plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hexadecimal binary numbers (in place of spaces) in your README.md. That's why it can't be parsed and represented as a markdown file:

Tip: make your editor display spaces/tabulation and other invisible characters. That's what I see when I open your README.md:

```
Ride my way<0x00>app<0x00>
<0x00>
<0x00>
```

So nothing to do with the way you display the badges.

I've removed these non asci-characters and just created a pull request (notice how github defines this change as `BIN` and can't display a diff):

[image]

And it's now displayed as it should:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Xavier! You are a life saver. Everything works perfectly now.